# how can I use openssl to download my ldap cert over port 389 instead of 636 (TLS)?

Tags: openldap, openssl

I've used to use the following command to download my server SSL certs from LDAP in order to add them to tomcat/java keystores:

openssl s_client -connect 10.140.136.192:636

Since LDAP SSL (port 636) has been deprecated, I don't have port 636 available anymore.  I've tried to find various incantations for `openssl s_client` such as `-starttls` and `-tls1_2` however none of them produce the certificate. What is the magic word to do this?

Comment: Two upstream issues: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/1733 and https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/1955

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenSSL supports [starttls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STARTTLS) for a number of protocols with s_client:

> `-starttls protocol`
>              send the protocol-specific message(s) to switch to TLS for communication.  protocol is a keyword for the intended protocol.  Currently, the only supported keywords are "`smtp`", "`pop3`", "`imap`", and "`ftp`".

which would allow you to easily retrieve the public certificate but LDAP isn't one them, unfortunately.

Since the upgrade to TLS is protocol specific you need a tool that understands the protocol.  That rules out OpenSSL.

I don't have a directory at hand but wouldn't the verbose `ldapsearch -Z -v -H ldap://ldap.example.com:389  ...` display the certificate as part of the debugging info?
A quick search shows that Apache Directory studio will [display the certificate](http://directory.apache.org/studio/users-guide/ldap_browser/tools_certificate_trust_dialog.html) too.

**Update:**

Openssl 1.1.1 included a [patch to add LDAP support (RFC 4511) to s_client](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/398b0bbdf71d852daf2e79d842cd0d307ec9f8f6)  and `-starttls ldap` is now supported. RHEL/CentOS 7 versions of openssl appear to have backported that update (and others) to the openssl 1.0.2k package they ship, as the manual now has 8 additional starttls protocols:

> `-starttls protocol`
>              send the protocol-specific message(s) to switch to TLS for communication.  protocol is a keyword for the intended protocol.  Currently, the only supported keywords are `smtp`, `pop3`, `imap`, `ftp`, **`xmpp`, `xmpp-server`, `irc`,
>              `postgres`, `lmtp`, `nntp`, `sieve` and `ldap`**.

Comment: No luck with that `ldapsearch` command. Strange. I don't see a clear way to retrieve an LDAP cert from a server (other than emailing/SSH) unless it is configured with deprecated LDAPS.  *EDIT*: `ldapsearch -d 255 -x -Z -H ldap://my.ldap.server` does display the cert but it's a Hex dump. Not so great for cutting and pasting, but it's something.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Currently no backport for Ubuntu LTS, but good to know.